# Representation theory of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, modular-representation-theory

The group $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is the group of two-by-two matrices with integer entries and determinant one. This is a very simple definition. Yet its representation theory seems quite wild to me (a PhD physics student) from the limited information I can find online... In particular, it seems it has uncountably many irreducible representations. I am also aware that  if we restrict ourselves to the class of representations with finite image and whose kernel can be described by congruences, the representation theory becomes way more well-behaved. These are the so-called congruence subgroups.

I would like to learn more about the representation theory of $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ beyond the classical textbook discussions restricted on congruence subgroups.

Any good general references (papers, book, ...) I could look into?

Comment: This group has a simple presentation, namely $\langle x,y\mid x^4=y^6=x^2y^{-3}=1\rangle$. So its representations are not that mysterious. Notably those factoring through $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ corresponds to pairs $(x,y)$ in the target group with $x^2=y^3=1$. Of course this is not exactly a representation, but spaces of representations should be accessible using this.

Comment: Thanks! Any references? I am not an expert so this would be helpful.

Comment: @DaveWasHere Re: references for the presentation (at least), this is not too difficult, and can be found e.g. in Serre's "Trees" on page 81, though the presentation was known since at least Reidemeister in the 30s, but I'm certain it was known explicitly earlier too.

Answer (score 13):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$The reason that there are uncountably many irreducible representations is not so bad, and gets at an important point: You shouldn't think of irreducible representations of a group like $\SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ individually, but rather as points in a space of representations, i.e. objects parameterized by a geometric space.

This is simplest to see for representations sending $-I \in \SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ to the identity, i.e. representations of $\PSL_2(\mathbb Z)$. By the [presentation YCor gave](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419795/representation-theory-of-textsl2-mathbbz#comment1078074_419795) $\PSL_2(\mathbb Z) = \langle x,y \mid x^2 =y^3 =1 \rangle$, such a representation is given by a matrix $X$ satisfying $X^2=1$ and a matrix $Y$ satisfying $Y^3=1$, and representations up to isomorphism are given by pairs of matrices up to conjugation.

For $n$-dimensional representations, say $n$ a multiple of $6$, it's not so hard to check that the space of matrices $X \in \GL_n(\mathbb C)$ with $X^2=1$ has dimension $n^2/2$ (over $\mathbb C$), and the space of matrices $Y \in \GL_n(\mathbb C)$ with $Y^3= 1$ has dimension $2n^2/3$, so the space of pairs has dimension $n^2/2 + 2n^2/3$, isomorphism classes of $n$-dimensional representations have dimension $n^2/2 +2n^2/3 - (n^2-1) = n^2/6+1$.

One can check that irreducible representations are an open subset, and thus that the space of irreducible representations has the same dimension.

So certainly there are uncountably many, because they're parameterized by a positive-dimensional manifold!

However, it's clear from this analysis that *this space* should be one of the primary objects of study in the representation theory here, as it is for representations of surface groups and in some other cases of interest.

Answer (score 9):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$The issue is that $\SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is very close to a free group, so it is not hard to map it to other groups, and in particular to produce lots of varied representations of it.

You might be interested to know that things are quite different for $\SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ when $n$ is at least $3$.  I wrote a note [The representation theory of $\operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb Z)$](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/RepTheorySLnZ.pdf) describing results of Margulis and Lubotzky giving a complete and fairly simple description of its representations.

Answer (score 2):

Far from being a specialist on the topic, section 4 of the article [$\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf), by K. Conrad discusses non-congruence subgroups.

Comment: This is a great article, but it doesn't have much to do with the representation theory, does it?