# Representation theory of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, homological-algebra, algebraic-groups

I want to understand the (complex) representation theory of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, the general linear group of the integers. I have gone through several representation theory texts but all of them present theory relevant to compact groups. What are the irreducible complex representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: There is rather a different story for $n=2$ and $n \ge 3$. For the related case of $SL_n(\mathbb Z)$ see e.g. here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419795/representation-theory-of-textsl2-mathbbz and here https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/RepTheorySLnZ.pdf

Answer (score 13):

For $n=2$, these groups are very close to free groups, so their representation theory is not very tractable.  For $n \geq 3$, however, there is a beautiful story arising from Margulis superrigidity.  I wrote this up for the special linear group [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/RepTheorySLnZ.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you please tell me how the representation theory of the subgroup $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ relates to that of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$? I am studying for a Physics PhD and I am sorry that it does not seems straight forward for me.

Comment: It’s a degree 2 extension, so there shouldn’t be a huge difference.  I would have to think a bit to figure out exactly what changes, but my guess is that there is a similar description of the proalgebraic completion.  You have to be a little careful since the Zariski closure of GL(n,Z) is not GL(n,R), but rather the group of matrices over the reals whose determinant is 1 or -1.

Comment: (sorry that this is probably not very understandable to physicists — these groups are significantly deeper and more complicated than the compact or semisimple Lie groups that you all tend to study).

Comment: If $n$ is odd, then $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}) \times \{ \pm \text{Id} \}$, so every irrep of $\text{GL}_n$ is an irrep of $\text{SL}_n$ tensored with one of the two one-dimensional reps of $\{ \pm 1 \}$.

Comment: I don't see any similarly easy trick for $n$ even.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Nice observation, I should have noticed that one!